# WKWebview using loadHTMLString trying to Adjust the Font size & use local custom font in Swift

Tags: swift, wkwebview

I am attempting to adjust my font size and custom local font in Swift. Right now the font is small and barely can see it and I am not sure how to add the local custom font to my WKWebview using loadHTMLString.

I am able to see my HTML on my app, I just am not sure how to adjust the font to a bigger size and add a custom font.

**The custom font I am using is "ProximaNova-Regular"
and I would also like to make the font size "22"**

This is the code I have so far.

Calling the WKWebView here

```
    var webViewDisplay: WKWebView = {
    let webView = WKWebView()
    webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
    return webView
}()
```

Then I am calling my HTMLString here.

```
  let htmlString = articleDataCell.body ?? ""
   webViewDisplay.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)
```